# finding constants of a continuous probability distribution when given parameters and probability

Tags: probability, continuity, normal-distribution

$X$ is a random variable & has normal distribution with mean $500$ & SD is $10$. If $P(a < X < b)=0.95$ find  the constants '$a$' and '$b$'

Comment: Do you know how to use the Normal Distribution Table?

Comment: Yah I know how to use the z table..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** In a standard normal distribution, $95\%$ of the area lies between $1.96$ and $-1.96$. Using the formula for z-score, we have
$$-1.96 = \frac{a-500}{10}$$
$$1.96 = \frac{b-500}{10}$$

Comment: So does that mean the 0.95 has no use in the question? Because from the Z table that I have,the Z values run from 0.0 to 3.9..so not so clear on your explanation please

Comment: The $0.95$ is needed to figure out the $1.96$ and $-1.96$. You can use a table to confirm these values. To find the left bound ($-1.96$), find the z-value that corresponds to 0.0250 in the chart, as that is the area that is not included **and** to the left. Similarly for the right bound, ($1.96$) find the z-value that corresponds to 0.9750

Comment: Oh I see what you mean by 95%, so asking how you landed at the 1.96 please

Comment: Why are we using the 0.0250? I have seen its corresponding to 1.96 but for the 0.9750 the probabilities don't reach that far on the table, they go up to 0.5 which corresponds to 0

Comment: $0.95$ is what we are looking for. That leaves $0.05$ remaining, because total area under the curve must add up to $1$. Now, for the remaining $0.05$, exactly half of it will be to the left of the area we want. $0.05 / 2 = 0.0250$

Comment: As for why the table doesn't correspond to $.9750$, perhaps you only have one half of the full table. There are many different formats for this table in textbooks and online, but they all can be used to give accurate results.

Comment: Wow, this answers my question.. Thank you very much on the prompt replies.. I really appreciate..

Comment: If you like the answer, you can upvote it and mark it as an accepted answer.  And welcome to the Math Stack Exchange!